# How do i force the Raspberry pi 2 to use the 3.5mm 4 pole video out

Tags: raspbian, display

Hello anyone reading this. I am trying hopelessly to get my Raspberry Pi 2 to output through its 3.5mm 4 pole jack. I have read that is had a option to send video out through that port.

Now I know I have my cabling correct. I have checked it with a meter. I also have a copy of the Raspberry Pi diagram that shows what pole the video is "hosted on". I know very little about how to edit the `config.txt` so this is just a cry for help because I have spent hours on this and I am lost. So thank you in advance to anyone that responds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to check/edit the config.txt file, for these relevant entries, *I think*; they are shamelessly copied from [elinux's RPi pages](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig), just skip typing in the bullet symbol and anything after and including the '#' comment start character:

> `hdmi_force_hotplug` Pretends HDMI hotplug signal is asserted so it appears a HDMI display is attached:
>
> - hdmi_force_hotplug=1 # Use HDMI mode even if no HDMI monitor is detected
>
> `hdmi_ignore_hotplug` Pretends HDMI hotplug signal is not asserted so it appears a HDMI display is not attached:
>
> - hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1 # Use composite mode even if HDMI monitor is detected
>
> `sdtv_mode` defines the TV standard for composite output (default=0), so use one of:
>
> - sdtv_mode=0    # Normal NTSC
> - sdtv_mode=1    # Japanese version of NTSC – no pedestal
> - sdtv_mode=2    # Normal PAL
> - sdtv_mode=3    # Brazilian version of PAL – 525/60 rather than 625/50, different subcarrier
>
> `sdtv_aspect` defines the aspect ratio for composite output (default=1):
>
> - sdtv_aspect=1  # 4:3
> - sdtv_aspect=2  # 14:9
> - sdtv_aspect=3  # 16:9

So, comment out/remove/set the value to `0` for the first of these, and insert/uncomment/change from 0 to 1 the second (*if necessary*) and tweak the third and fourth for your geographical/system requirements.

To change these setting *on the fly* you will probably want to experiment with the `tvservice <option>... <arguments>...` command (may need to be run via `sudo`) but as it can change where the local video is displayed from the Pi it is useful to login over ssh and work from there to see the results, also I found in practice that when changing settings for the current display on the Pi it blanks that out and you will want to use a local keyboard to bring the previous contents into view; EITHER: use something like `Alt-F2` to switch from VT1 (virtual terminal '1') to VT2 and then `Alt-F1` to switch back if using a non-GUI (full screen console) display OR `Cntl-Alt-F2` to switch from a GUI to VT2 and then `Alt-F1` to return to the GUI (XWindow) display.

*Note: the config.txt can contain multiple instances of some of these with different values, I think the last one (that is NOT commented out with a leading `#`) of each is the one used so it would be wise to comment out the earlier ones to avoid confusing yourself.*

Comment: Thank you SlySven for your response!! It worked beautifully! I can not thank you enough for writing such a detailed post.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you either have composite output (multi-pole jack) enabled or HDMI output enabled.  You can not have both at the same time.

If a HDMI device is detected at boot then the output will be HDMI, otherwise it will be composite.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I do not have any HDMI plugged in currently though.